# Convert fragment shader gradient result from black to transparent in GL ES

Tags: math, three.js, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I'm trying to generate realistic stars for an open source game I'm working on. I'm generating the stars using principles covered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk). I'm using the [three.js](https://threejs.org/) library in a Chromium engine (NW.js). The problem I've found is that the star glow fades into black instead of into transparency.

Whilst it looks nice for single star,

[image]

multiple stars have a serious problem:

[image]

My code is as follows:

**Vertex shader**

```
attribute vec3 glow;
varying vec3 vGlow;

void main() {
  vGlow = glow;
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 100.0;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
varying vec3 vGlow;

void main() {
  float starLuminosity  = 250.0;
  float invRadius = 60.0;
  float invGlowRadius = 2.5;

  // Get position relative to center.
  vec2 position = gl_PointCoord;
  position.x -= 0.5;
  position.y -= 0.5;

  // Airy disk calculation.
  float diskScale = length(position) * invRadius;
  vec3 glow = vGlow / pow(diskScale, invGlowRadius);
  glow *= starLuminosity;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(glow, 1.0);
}
```

I've tried discarding pixels that are darker, but this does not solve the problem, it only hides it a tad:

```
if (gl_FragColor.r < 0.1 && gl_FragColor.g < 0.1 && gl_FragColor.b < 0.1) {
  discard;
}
```

[image]

The actual effect I'm after is as follows,

[image]

but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this effect in the fragment shader because you are rendering multiple meshes or primitives. You have to enable [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) before rendering the geometry:

```js
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Also make sure that the [Depth test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) is disabled.

Additionally you must set the alpha channel from. e.g.:

<s>`gl_FragColor = vec4(glow, 1.0);`</s>

```c
vec4(glow, (glow.r+glow.g.+glow.b)/3.0 * 1.1 - 0.1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the problem and looks perfect. This has been very enlightening